# Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php

```
$cat_insert=$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO tbl_category (service_name,isactive,isHome,image,order_id,footer_show) values ('$service_name','$isactive','$isHome','$filePath','$order_id',$footer_show)") or trigger_error(mysql_error());


 echo $mysqli->error;

 $row_cnt = $cat_insert->num_rows;
 echo "Rows=$cat_rows";
```

Comment: Need to update your question to be more clear on what is your issue and not just post a code snippet

Comment: Your question/problem is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your variables actually exist. ALso, your row count does not really make any sense. Are you trying to get the last insert id?